# Analytical solution for adding up this sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there an analytical solution for adding up this sequence of numbers?

$$
n + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{4} + \frac{n}{8} + \ldots + 1
$$

For example, let $n=32$,

$$
32 + \frac{32}{2} + \frac{32}{4} + \frac{32}{8}+ \ldots + 1
=
32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + \ldots + 1
$$

I *believe*, we can express the formula like this:

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\log(n)} \frac{n}{2^i}$$

However, is there an analytical solution to this problem?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244817/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1939788/42969

Comment: looks like a geometric series

Comment: Thank you it was indeed a duplicate. I actually did try googling for this. I didn't even know what key word to search..